# Libreoffice command line convert suddenly fails

Tags: libreoffice, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Currently I am using LO to convert RTF documents to PDF. I am using the WSL system from windows to run ubuntu and run the LO command:

`"/mnt/c/Program Files/LibreOffice/Program/soffice.exe" --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir "/output/" *.rtf`

It all works fine and dandy and then after 661 documents (Don't know if somebody recognizes it that something happens after that amount of documents):

`convert C:\test\input\00001261_000871.rtf -> C:\output\00001261_000871.pdf using filter : writer_pdf_Export Error: Please verify input parameters... (SfxBaseModel::impl_store <file:///C:/output//00001261_000871.pdf> failed: 0xc10(Error Area:Io Class:Write Code:16))`

All the documents after the first time this errors occurs fails with the same error. When I manually convert the above document `00001261_000872.rtf` it works perfectly (it always fails when it gets to that document)

What might be happening here? The error (0xc10) shows that has a bad write or something?

The idea to do it this way came from the LO website:
https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Faq/General/150

Comment: I am running into a similar issue. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No I actually did find any problem regarding this problem... havent tried it quite a bit actually still find it strange it does this ...

Answer (score 1):

Well after some time I finally got the chance to look at it this again. But this time from a full dual boot Ubuntu installation.

I came across a topic that said there was a limitation on the command line of Linux that only 249 arguments are accepted and then it just stops.

Well after creating a simple load balancer to create directories of max 200 files and just run libre over each folder everything works flawlessly and I can convert as many documents as needed (you just spin up a new libre instance every 200 files).

If this works in wsl? I am not sure, I just spin up an Ubuntu vm in azure when I need to convert a batch of files, copy the files to the vm, convert them, bring them back to a local share and shutdown the vm. Why? And just a docker and use the listener? Because just copying the files, converting them locally and copying them back is just plain faster...

The bash script I am currently using (`bash conversion.sh <directory where the files are stored>`), I need to convert RTF documents and such I filter on `*.rtf` files)

I specify the the `-env` variable to spin up multiple OL instances to allow for even more speed when converting the files. Took arround 1 minute to convert 1000 RTF files to PDF.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
baseDirectory="/home/user/test/conversion"

# Check if directory is specified.
if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo "No input directory specified."
    exit
fi

# Balance files to directory, each directory contains max of 200
# This is done cause Linux has a shell limit of 249 with libreoffice.
rtfs=($1/*.rtf)
for ((i=0; i < ${#rtfs[@]}; i += 200)); do
    printf -v b "${baseDirectory}/balancer/%03d" $((++n))
    mkdir -p $b && mv -t $b "${rtfs[@]:$i:200}"
done

# Loop balance directies and let libreoffice do its magic in converting the RTF files to PDF.
# Remove the balance directory after the conversion is done.
for d in ${baseDirectory}/balancer/*; do
    id=${d: -3}
    soffice "-env:UserInstallation=file:///${baseDirectory}/environments/${id}" \
            --headless --convert-to pdf "$d"/*.rtf \
            --outdir $1 > ${baseDirectory}/environments/output_${id}.log 2>&1 && \
            rm -rf "$d" &
done

wait
echo "Conversion done"
```